# Why I can't get the naive timestamp for the first day of year 1 (0001-01-01)

Tags: python, pyspark, time

With PySpark I want to store following date under the TimestampType in Spark: 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z. It fails when trying to access the data (i.e. with DataFrame.head()) with the following error:

`Year 0 is out of range`

Which is completely baffling as I am not using year 0.

I did a bit digging into the code and found PySpark is doing the following:
`return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts // 1000000).replace(microsecond=ts % 1000000)`

I did some tests and it seems the issues with timestamps starts for 0001-01-01T23:59:59Z so it seems it cannot deal with "the first day of year 1".

I have tested it with the below:

```
d = datetime(1,1,1,23,59,59)
print(d.timestamp())
```

What's the expected solution for the problem? It feels like a bug in PySpark? (Or even in Python as I found this: https://bugs.python.org/issue31212, but I have issues not only with "datetime.min" (I could imagine root cause is the same?)

Comment: `timestamp` is documented as relying on an underlying system call, so it may have restrictions that have nothing to do with Python.